# GEKKO - MINLP in Matrix Form - Errors using m.axb()

Tags: optimization, gekko, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to solve a MINLP problem using GEKKO. My code is the following:

```py
m = GEKKO(remote = True)
m.options.SOLVER = 3

m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                # minlp iterations with integer solution
                'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                # treat minlp as nlp
                'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                # maximum deviation from whole number
                'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                # covergence tolerance
                'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

# Array Variable
rows  = nb_phases + 3*b_max*(nb_phases+1)#48
columns = 1
x = np.empty((rows,columns),dtype=object)
for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1):
    for j in range(columns):
        x[i,j] = m.Var(value = xinit[i,j], lb = LB[i,j], ub = UB[i,j], integer = False)

for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases):
    for j in range(columns):
        x[i,j] = m.Var(value = xinit[i,j], lb = LB[i,j], ub = UB[i,j], integer = True)

# Constraints
#m.axb(A = A,b = B, x = x, etype = '<=', sparse = False)
m.axb(A,B, etype = '<=',sparse=False) 

#m.axb(A = A_eq,b = B_eq, x = x, etype = '=', sparse = False)
m.axb(A_eq,B_eq, etype = '=',sparse=False)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        m.Minimize((x[i,j]-i*j)**2)

#Solver
m.solve(disp = True)
```

When calling the axb function, if I declare the variable x in the arguments as the following:

```py
m.axb(A = A,b = B, x = x, etype = '<=', sparse = False)
```

I get the error : List x must be composed of GEKKO parameters or variables. I don't really understand why I get this error since x is a gekko variable.

If I don't declare the variable x in the arguments of the axb function:

```py
m.axb(A,B, etype = '<=',sparse=False)
```

I get the following error: AXB Missing Configuration File, Error: AXB object missing: axb1.txt, Example config file: axb1.txt

I was thinking maybe the issue is that x is not defined as an array. Therefore, considering x[i,j], I tried to explicit the equation Ax<=b by coding the matrix product A.x in a loop to avoid calling m.axb but I am not sure how to declare the equations after. My code is the following:

```py
Ax = []

for i in range(rows):
    temp = []
    for j in range(columns):
        temp.append(A[i,j]*x[j,0])
    Ax.append(sum(temp))

for i in range(rows):
    m.Equations(Ax[i] <= B[i])
```

I get the error: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Is anyone able to help me figure out how to solve this problem?
Is there a way of defining x as an array? (Since some of its elements are integers and some aren't)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works with the newer version of Gekko that is not yet released but is available on GitHub. You'll need to put the newest version of `gekko.py` (v1.0) in the `Lib/site_packages/gekko` folder and the local executable (`apm.exe` for Windows, `apm_mac` for MacOS, `apm` for Linux) in the `Lib/site_packages/gekko/bin` folder to use `remote=False`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote = False)
m.options.SOLVER = 3
nb_phases = 2
b_max = 3

m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                # minlp iterations with integer solution
                'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                # treat minlp as nlp
                'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                # maximum deviation from whole number
                'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                # covergence tolerance
                'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

# Array Variable
rows  = nb_phases + 3*b_max*(nb_phases+1)#48
columns = 1
xinit = np.ones(rows)
LB = np.zeros(rows)
UB = np.ones(rows)*10.0
#x = m.Array(m.Var,(rows))
x = np.empty(rows,dtype=object)
for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1):
    x[i] = m.Var(value = xinit[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i], integer = False)

for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases):
    x[i] = m.Var(value = xinit[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i], integer = True)

# Constraints
#m.axb(A = A,b = B, x = x, etype = '<=', sparse = False)
A = np.ones((1,rows)); B = np.zeros(1)
m.axb(A,B,x,etype = '<=',sparse=False) 

#m.axb(A = A_eq,b = B_eq, x = x, etype = '=', sparse = False)
m.axb(A,B,x,etype = '=',sparse=False)

for i in range(rows):
    m.Minimize((x[i]-i)**2)

#Solver
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp = True)
```

This produces the solution:

```py
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  2
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  29
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  58
   Equations    :  29
   Residuals    :  29
 
 Number of state variables:    29
 Number of total equations: -  2
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    27
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:     -0.00 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj:  7.71E+03 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.019000000000000003 sec
 Objective      :  7714.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Dear John, thanks a lot for your answer. Now the code is running but the solution doesn't seem correct. I will post my new question in another post. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at the new question.